# link separate/conditional/unique stylesheets for various browsers

Tags: php, jquery, css

What is the current best practice for pointing gecko, opera, msie, webkit, etc., to their own additional stylesheets?

Browser sniffing is out? Most of what I'm finding online are old posts from 2008, or theoretical arguments about right vs. wrong, or how to use  or whatever.

There must be something more sophisticated that we can use for this. Something jquery or php that says, (pseudo-code), "IF moz, @import url(moz.css)" or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Detect browser from the useragent and include appropriate css for that browser.

```
$browser = get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], true);

switch ($browser['browser']) {
    case "IE": //load ie specific css
                break;
    case "Firefox":
    case "Mozilla":   //load gecko specific css
        break;

    case "Safari":  //load safari css
           break;
    case "Opera": //load opera css
          break;

    default:
        echo '<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
}
```

Here is a [detailed article](http://www.koodoz.com.au/klog/development/getting-phps-get_browser-function-to-work-on-your-site/) on get_browser() function.

Comment: This looks like it's exactly what I need, but can you be more specific? I'm useless with code. What would be the exact snippet for detecting opera and gecko, and point them to their own relevant stylesheets?

Comment: you have to use browser_info() function like get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], true); you'll get what type of browser it is, but for using this function you need to made some change in your script

Answer (score 0):

Detecting specific browsers is a bad idea, as different versions can have different features which you may not be aware of. A better solution is to use something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com) to detect *features*, and style accordingly.

If you *must* detect different rendering engines for whatever reason though, in PHP it's relatively straightforward using the [`browser_info()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) method:

```
<head>
    ...
    <!-- Stylesheets for all browsers -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <?php
    $browser    = get_browser(null, true);

    switch($browser['browser']){
        case 'Firefox':
            // User is using Firefox
            $style  = 'firefox.css';
            break;

        case 'Safari':
            // User is using Safari
            $style  = 'safari.css';
            break;
    }

    if(isset($style)){
        // Specific browser stylesheet set - add to page
        ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $style;?>" />
    <?php } ?>
</head>
```

Comment: the word "switch" threw me off, from what I gather this code would switch styles, but I just need something that tacks on an additional stylesheet for certain browsers.

Comment: @user1691389 I've updated the example to try to be a bit clearer. `switch` statements are a common feature in many programming languages – have a look at [the page on the PHP manual about them](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for a more fundamental explanation!

Comment: the very first line in both examples is giving errors. I appreciate your help, guys, but I know when to quit. I'll just use one gigantic stylesheet, it's not the end of the world.

Comment: @user1691389 what error is it giving? You need to have your php.ini settings set, as the manual says: "In order for this to work, your [browscap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.browscap) configuration setting in php.ini must point to the correct location of the browscap.ini file on your system."

Comment: @user1691389 I'm guessing you're using a shared host, or some other environment where you can't edit the php.ini file. If so, you can use the [phpbrowscap](https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap) project to replicate that functionality. Then, replace the `get_browser` area in my example with something like `$bc = new Browscap('path/to/cache'); $browser = $bc->getBrowser(); switch($browser['Browser']){ ...`